# How to Implement "Else If" In Merge Field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, css, conditional

It is possible to write two individual if statements in a style tag for an `<apex:column>`?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Priority" style="{!IF(AgentInfo.priorityNumber = 1, 'background-color: #98D2F1', 'background-color: '), ELSE IF(AgentInfo.Username = {!userEmail}, 'background-color: green', 'background-color: red ')}">
```

I have read up on using AND but continued to get syntax errors.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Priority" style="{!AND(AgentInfo.priorityNumber = 1, AgentInfo.Username = {!userEmail}), 'background-color: #98D2F1', 'background-color: ', 'background-color: green', 'background-color: red '}">
```

I am unable to find an example of someone else doing this so I am not sure if it is even possible. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that the `IF` function [syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) is `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. So if you want an "else if" clause, put another `IF` function in place of `value_if_false`.

```
IF(condition1, 'value 1', IF(condition2, 'value 2', 'value 3'));
```

The above is functionally equivalent to the following `Apex`:

```
if (condition 1)
{
    return 'value 1';
}
else if (condition 2)
{
    return 'value 2';
}
else
{
    return 'value 3';
}
```

That second `value_if_false` is your fallback if *neither* condition is true.

---

Note also that you are already within a merge field (`style="{!...}"`), so you should not wrap `userEmail` in a second, redundant merge field. The final value should be (indented for readability):

```
{!IF(
    AgentInfo.priorityNumber = 1,
    'background-color: #98D2F1',
    IF(
        AgentInfo.Username = userEmail, // remove {!}
        'background-color: green',
        'background-color: red '
    )
)}
```

Comment: is it possible to do just another IF statement? `<apex:column headerValue="Priority" style="{!IF(AgentInfo.priorityNumber = 1, 'background-color: #98D2F1', 'background-color: '),  IF(AgentInfo.Username = !userEmail, 'background-color: green', 'background-color: red ')}">` or would it be possible to add an else statement at the end of your example? Like so: `"{!IF(AgentInfo.priorityNumber = 1,'background-color: #98D2F1', IF(AgentInfo.Username = userEmail, 'background-color: green', 'background-color: red '), background-color:blue')}"` ?

Comment: The third value is what you get if neither conditional is true (`background-color: red`). You would never get past the second `value_if_false`.

Comment: okay that makes sense. Do you know if there is a limit on how many if statements you can use?

Comment: Honestly, if your logic is more complicated than that, you should just calculate the style in `Apex`. But no, there is technically no hard limit. In a formula field you would eventually hit a character limit, but I'm not sure if they apply in a merge field. Note that if you have a few different `IF` conditions around the same value, you can use a `CASE` function instead. It's just not an option here because your conditions are on different values.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was just curious for the future. As usual, you are the best!

Comment: @Olivia You can make the expressions as complex as you want. However, be aware that expressions can bloat your "internal state" view state usage (the 135k view state governor limit). You should *prefer* to use Apex Code whenever possible.